# How do I set my htpassw for TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In the past I've had no probems with commits/updates via TortoiseSVN but recently I've put my files online so I put a .htpassw in my site root. And now I can't commit anymore with the expected error message:

```
Error: svn: Commit failed (detals follow):svn: OPTIONS of "svn/mywebsite/path": 500 Internal Server Error
```

The error is expected, but how do I go around this? How can I "tell" TortoiseSVN" which htpassw username/password to use?

**TL; DR;**: If I'm committing files into a directory which has an .htpassw file, how can I make TortoiseSVN bypass that?

Answer (score 0):

As first you should provide more info on error from apache logs, this is very general error.

Related to password, Tortoise will always ask you for password if it required.
Then you can mark checkbox "remember" so it will remember it for later.
You can clear saved passwords in TortoiseSVN settings -> Saved Data -> Authentication data -> Clear

Error you posted is probably not a result of authentication , but apache configuration.
Maybe post some config and more info from logs.

Comment: Well this is not a repository user/password so Tortoise doesn't ask for it. This is an auth requested from apache, as you say. Don't think error logs is necessary, I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to bypass it. If I'm comitting files into a directory which has an .htpassw file, how can I make TortoiseSVN bypass that?